# Re-orient (not rotate) PDF content from portrait to landscape

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file that looks like this:

[image]

All the solutions on the internet say I should rotate the PDF to get it to landscape, so I used `pdftk` and got this result:

[image]

This just rotates the PDF contents, which is still in portrait. **When I print it, it comes out exactly the same for both PDF types.**

What I want is to re-orient the content from the first image into landscape mode so that the tables are spaced out more nicely. Picture 4 tables in landscape vs. the portrait mode they are now on.

I cannot share an example of it, as that would be the solution I am looking for.

How do I re-orient the content into landscape?

Comment: Generally you would go back to the source application and lay the tables out in your preferred way.

Comment: @roaima if I have another copy of this document with each table on a single PDF page, can I orient them into landscape from that version? I do not have a source besides the PDFs

Comment: I have no idea. The "tables" could be graphics or they could be text. The page could be a single graphic that happens to visualise four tables. Without taking time to analyse the PDF there's no way anyone can tell

Comment: @ElCapistan If you have a copy with each table on a single PDF page, you could use `pdfjam` like this: `pdfjam  --landscape --nup 2x2 input.pdf --delta "1in 0in" -o output.pdf`. The `--delta` option puts extra space between the embedded pages horizontally and vertically; adjust as needed.

Comment: thanks @frabjous I tried what you said but the display is super small when using this command. Is there a way to make it larger using pdfjam?